# AngularJS select tag validation

Tags: angularjs

I am missing something very simple here, i got an array in my controller as follows

```
    $scope.roles = [
        {id: 0, label: 'Choose a Role'},
        {id: 1, label: 'Administrator'},
        {id: 2, label: 'Super User'}
    ];
```

And following is my select tag in the view

```
<select ng-options="role.id as role.label for role in roles" ng-model="myForm.role" ng-required="true"> 
</select>
```

How can i validate that the user chose `Administrator` or `Super User` and not `Choose a Role`?

Comment: I added a fiddle to my answer so you can have a working example. Please let me know if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit2 :** https://jsfiddle.net/3kL9rmp8/

**Edit :** I made you a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/fgpg9zvn/

You can add an option this way :

```
<select ng-options="role.id as role.label for role in roles" 
        ng-model="myForm.role"
        ng-required="true">
       <option value="" disabled selected style="display: none;"> Chose a role </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Actually it is almost there, except that the value of Chose a role must be `0` and also i have to set the form to invalid

Comment: @user3052526 Have a look at my Edit2 fiddle -> the form is set to invalid if no value is chosen (see the <span> message) but I don't understand why you want "choose a role" message to have a value as you can't submit the form when this value is chosen ?

Comment: Its a requirement from the back end api sadly. gonna have a look now

Answer (score 0):

From the HTML you can use:

```
<div ng-if="myForm.role == 'Chose a role">
Your code when 'Chose a role;
</div>
```

JS:

```
if ($scope.myForm.role == 'Chose a role) {
   Your code here
}
```

Comment: But how will `myForm` become invalid in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Try this neat and simple solution. 
Use this HTML to have select element.

**HTML:**

```
<select ng-model="myForm.role" 
        ng-options="role.id as role.label for role in roles"
        ng-change="fillTheDDL(role.id, role.label)"> 

  <option value="">Chose a role</option>

</select>
```

Use this JS to get the desired functionality.

**JS:**

```
$scope.fillTheDDL= function (ID, Label) {
    if (Label != "Choose a Role") {
     // Your favorite code here       
    }
    else {
        // You don't wanna use it
    }
};
```